# How to customize a QtQuick 2 component style while enable is false

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

When I set `enabled` property on a `ComboBox` for example, then it gets "greyed out". As far as I can tell it draws a layer above the component with a certain opacity so the original design is visible but becomes slightly faded. How can I tweak this effect?

I tried to change my components background color based on the `enabled` property's state, but that didn't help. For example I have set my background color to red, when the `enabled` property was false, but it didn't become red, it became more like a light red due to the overlay what I was describing above.

A simple code example:

```
ComboBox {
  id: control
  enabled: false

  model: ["First", "Second", "Third"]

  background: Rectangle {
    color: control.enabled ? "transparent" : "red"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? I believe this was fixed in Qt 5.7.1.

Comment: This particular commit, which landed to Qt 5.7.1, moved the opacity statement from the control's root element to the building blocks, so now if you replace the background, you have full control over its opacity: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/commit/src/imports/controls/ComboBox.qml?id=f6acc98f3a96ab6cafedfe2a3f097a1974abad16

Comment: PS. The name of the property is `enabled`.

Comment: Yea, that is a typo. Thanks though. I am using Qt 5.7.0 but I am upgrading to Qt 5.7.1 and will check if that fixes it. Thanks for the hints. I will get back as soon as I tried with Qt 5.7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @jpnurmi suggested, the source of my problem was fixed in Qt 5.7.1.

```
ComboBox {
  id: control
  enabled: false

  model: ["First", "Second", "Third"]

  opacity: 1 // *

  background: Rectangle {
    color: control.enabled ? "transparent" : "red"
  }
}
```

* = Adding this here, will overwrite the default opacity behaviour and then it can be controlled manually through the background component for example.